# R: change the values in column based on another vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this little bit tricky(for me) question:

I have data.frame with 3 columns:

```
    LA       CA         GA
1 1.288298 4.360709 -0.1440910
2 1.870277 5.218541  0.9997955
3 3.452725 5.250283  1.6460251
4 3.440450 6.035890  0.8467339
5 4.158738 4.805809 -0.3970444
6 3.024154 6.521119  0.7635716
```

and I also have vector with 3 elements called transform:

```
transform=c("log","","log")
```

So, I need if first element in transform has a "log", then do `exp` function on first column and etc.

How can I do that? I think in the way of using `ifelse` with `mapply`, but I'm not sure...

Comment: Try: `exp(dat[,which(transform %in% "log")])`

Comment: Unfortunately, this not work for me

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: No errors, i get a data frame with 500 obs. and 0 variables

Comment: I can`t reproduce the error, it works with the example provided.

Comment: Oh snap, my transform was a wrong, now it work! That could be an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `exp(dat[,which(transform %in% "log")])`

Comment: Interesting thing is that command left only columns where "log", but I need all three columns left

Comment: Just do `dat[,which(transform %in% "log")] <- exp(dat[,which(transform %in% "log")])`